# How to get data from file and put the result in a new file in C?

Tags: c, file, input, output, structure

I am working on a programm which gets a data about books (in a structure) from a file. Then it searches for the cities where the cheapest books are sold. Generally, this programm gets a file (**input_data.txt**) like:

```
2
Book Title 1
10
200
Author 1
2021
Publisher 1
City 1
Book Title 2
15
150
Author 2
2022
Publisher 2
City 2
```

As a result, it outputs the **output_data.txt** file, which has cities with the cheeapest books:

```
City 1
```

There is my code on C:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct izdatel {
    int god;
    char naz[100];
    char gor[100];
};

struct Book {
    char title[100];
    int price;
    int numPages;
    char author[100];
    struct izdatel publisherInfo;
};

void check_number(const char name[], int *s, FILE *input_data) {
    int ret_code;
    do {
        //printf("Input %s:\n", name);
        ret_code = fscanf(input_data, "%d", s);
        while (getchar() != '\n');  // clear the buffer (as not using fgets)
    } while (ret_code != 1 || *s <= 0);
}

void check_year(const char name[], int *s, FILE *input_data) {
    int ret_code;
    do {
        //printf("Input %s (between 1458 and 2024):\n", name);
        ret_code = fscanf(input_data, "%d", s);
        while (getchar() != '\n');  
    } while (ret_code != 1 || *s < 1458 || *s > 2024);
}

void check_string(const char name[], char s[], FILE *input_data) {
    int invalid_input;
    do {
        invalid_input = 0;
        //printf("Input %s:\n", name);
        fscanf(input_data, "%s", s);
        while (getchar() != '\n'); 

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
            if (!isalpha(s[i]) && !isspace(s[i])) {
                invalid_input = 1;
                printf("Invalid input. Please enter a string without numbers or special characters.\n");
                break;
            }
        }

    } while (invalid_input || strlen(s) == 0);
}

void input(struct Book *books, const int numStructs, FILE *input_data) {
    fscanf(input_data, "%d", &numStructs);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < numStructs; i++) {
        //printf("Book #%d\n", i + 1);
        check_string("Title", books[i].title, input_data);
        check_number("Price", &books[i].price, input_data);
        check_number("Number of pages", &books[i].numPages, input_data);
        check_string("Author", books[i].author, input_data);

        //printf("Publishing company:\n");
        check_year("Year of publication", &books[i].publisherInfo.god, input_data);
        check_string("Publisher name", books[i].publisherInfo.naz, input_data);
        check_string("Publishing city", books[i].publisherInfo.gor, input_data);
    }
}


void solution(struct Book *books, const int numStructs, FILE *output_data){
    float minPrice = books[0].price;
    for (int i = 0; i < numStructs; i++) {
        if (books[i].price < minPrice) {
            minPrice = books[i].price;
        }
    }

    fprintf(output_data, "\nCities where the cheapest books are published:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < numStructs; i++) {
        if (books[i].price == minPrice) {
            fprintf(output_data, "%s\n", books[i].publisherInfo.gor);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int numStructs;
    FILE *inputFile;

    struct Book books[numStructs];
    // input file
    char *inputFilename = "input_data.txt";
    char *outputFilename = "output_data.txt";

    inputFile = fopen(inputFilename, "r");
    FILE *outputFile = fopen(outputFilename, "w");
    
    if (inputFile == NULL || outputFile == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening files.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (inputFile) {
        input(books, numStructs, inputFile);
        solution(books, numStructs, outputFile);
    } else {
        printf("Failed to open the input file.\n");
    }
    
    fclose(inputFile);
    fclose(outputFile);

    return 0;
}
```

I've been racking my brain solving this problem. Please, help me. I will be truly grateful!

Comment: How many books can be present for one city? How should we handle if multiple books are there? How are we to compare how cheap is City1 vs. City2 if there are different books there? Are we to compare the prices of different books?

Comment: Your post does not ask a question, outside the broad “question” in the title. Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions. Edit the post to ask a specific question. If there is a bug, provide a [mre].

Comment: We do not have more than one book in every city.

Comment: I have done all that is needed in the task, but my programm is not working and I do not why. I have problems with working with files as I don't know how to add structure from a file to a programm and then add the result in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do short, review everything.

To do long, First of all:

```
int         numStructs;        // is const on all fonction call why not here to?
struct Book books[numStructs]; // numStructs not define and use
```

The parsing is your only problem on a program like that.
You need to find patterns in your file to know what information you have.
You also want to avoid thing like that :

```
char title[100];
```

You never know the size of the string you gonna have in your input file.
Take a sheet of paper and think about it.
No one here will give you a ready to use code.

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right: I've spent a lot of much time, but now my code is working and I understand every line in it. Here it is: https://github.com/5724gnvasya/Structures-and-files-in-C (for the future programmers)